# What Meteor template helper functions are available to subtemplates?

Tags: templates, meteor

I have a Meteor (v0.8) template inside another:

```
<template name="vehicles">
    {{wheels}}
    {{>hovercraft}}
</template>

<template name="hovercraft">
    {{eels}}
</template>
```

I want to define the template functions, `wheels` and `eels`, on the *outer* template (`vehicles`):

```
Template.vehicles.wheels = function() { console.log("wheels"); }
Template.vehicles.eels = function() { console.log("eels in the vehicles"); }
```

But then `eels` is not found. Of course defining it on the inner template (`hovercraft`) works:

```
Template.hovercraft.eels = function() { console.log("eels in the hovercraft"); }
```

What are the rules for how template functions are inherited by child templates?  Can `hovercraft` inherit the `vehicles` functions?  I regularly find myself needing this as I refactor large templates into smaller ones.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use package [meteor-template-extension](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-template-extension) to inherit helpers from template.

You can also pass arguments to subtemplate like that:

```
<template name="tParent">
   {{> tChild h1=helper1 h2=helper2}}
</template>

<template name="tChild">
   {{h1}}
   {{h2}}
</template>

Template.tParent.helpers({
    helper1: function () {
      return "helper1"
    },
    helper2: function () {
      return "helper2" 
    }
  });
```

The thing is that above approach pass result of helper and not reference to it.
However it still is useful in some cases.